# How to define custom log level in WildFly 10

Tags: wildfly, java.util.logging, wildfly-10

In `standalone.xml` we have the following:

```xml
<root-logger>
  <level name="INFO"/>
  <handlers>
    <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
    <handler name="FILE"/>
  </handlers>
</root-logger>
```

How can I add something like:

```xml
<level name="MYLEVEL"/>
```

Is this possible to do in WildFly 10 Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard [`java.util.logging.Level`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Level.html#parse-java.lang.String-) used by the `LogManager` allows you to pass an integer value of your custom level.  For example, if your `MYLEVEL` has a value of `2000` you can use the number instead of the name.

```xml
<root-logger>
  <level name="2000"/>
  <handlers>
    <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
    <handler name="FILE"/>
  </handlers>
</root-logger>
```

To use a custom level by the level name you have to include that binary in the boot class path.

Comment: I tried to add something like "50010" but i am getting the below error " Message: "WFLYLOG0026: Log level 50010 is invalid.". Can you please correct me here? And where should this "MYLEVEL" be defined.. Can you please share an example? I am looking for something which can be added in standalone.xml instead of in code.. thanks

Comment: The validation fails because the level attribute validator checks against specific log levels. What is the reason for using a custom level?